# Export preprocessor macro in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I want to export preprocessor macro to an internal makefile from the main makefile in a particular target.

example:
Main_Makefile

```
target1 :
   CXXFLAGS+=-DNewFlag=NewFlag
   cd some_directory; make
```

Here I want to use value of CXXFLAGS which is -DNewFlag=NewFlag and is only defined under target1 in some_directory/make

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: export variable cannot be change therefore use another variable name to do that ...

Comment: Ankur, I dint get what you meant.

Comment: dont use CXXFLAG as export variable ..

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to append to a variable from the command line, unless you've made arrangements for it in the makefile of the subdirectory.

The simplest thing to do is use a different variable, like this:

```
target1:
        cd some_directory && $(MAKE) EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=-DNewFlag=NewFlag
```

(note you should *always* use `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` when invoking a sub-make, never `make` directly.)

Then in the subdirectory makefile you do something like this:

```
CXXFLAGS += $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)
```